# Do I need to put 'the' in 'Brightman has released the Harem album'?

Tags: articles, formal-language

I am writing this sentence in a very formal way. the sentence is:

> For instance, the artist Sarah Brightman has released **the** Harem album in 2013.

Do I need to put **the** before **Harem** ?

Side note: I know that the sentence could be rephrased to *'Sarah Brightman has release ....'*, which maybe be better than mine sentence, but for now I'm just asking about the **the** before **Harem**

Comment: We don't usually employ the Present Perfect when a specific time marker is used, like "in 2013". And we are trying not to use wide-ranging tags like "grammar" for posts that are quite specific, like posts about the usage of articles.

Comment: @CowperKettle I am with you when it comes to *released* instead of *has released*. However, I believe that grammar is a correct tag here.

Comment: [We've had a lot of discussions about 'grammar'](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t?lq=1)

Comment: Grammar doesn't really add any information to the articles tag, I was in the process of fixing it up at the same time CowperKettle did.

Comment: @ColleenV The title is wrong now,

Comment: @ColleenV the title is wrong now,

Comment: We're trying to help you get a good response to your question - you may always roll back any edit someone else makes. About the title, you might find this helpful: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/please-use-specific-titles-dont-just-ask-is-this-grammatically-correct

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few issues with your sentence.

My recommended version would read:

> For instance, the artist Sarah Brightman released **her** "Harem" album in 2013.

"Has" is incorrect in this.  While you can say something like "He has eaten all of the cake", this is a statement of the recent past that is still ongoing. The cake is still gone. Yes, the album is still out, but it **was released**, it is a single point in time and now it is simply "released".

We often denote some ownership by saying "her" or "his" in relation to authored content. There may be dozens of albums titled "Harem", so clarifying that it's Brightman's album helps.

Also, depending on what [style guide](http://For%20instance,%20the%20artist%20Sarah%20Brightman%20has%20released%20the%20Harem%20album%20in%202013.) you're using, the album title should be in either quotes or italics.